# Trouble Using NSKeyedUnarchiver during init

Tags: ios, nskeyedarchiver

I have created a FacebookManager singleton that gets called on a background thread when my app launches.  Everything is working just fine with the facebook manager the singleton, the app etc.  However, when the app first launches, it is quite a few seconds before it is useful because the facebook manager has not finished doing its thing yet.  So what I want to do, is use NSKeyedArchiver to save the facebookManager and all its dictionaries so that upon launch, the app has a navigable interface while the facebook data is being updated in the background. Make sense?

All within the FacebookManager.m, first, when the manager is done updating the friends dictionaries, etc, I call the method that saves the data:

```
- (BOOL)saveFacebookData
{
    // returns success or failure
    NSString *path = [self archivePath]; // just a helper method

    return [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self toFile:path];
}
```

Then in init, I am trying this, which doesn't seem to work. :

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    NSString *path = [self archivePath];
    self = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];

    // If the manager hadn't been saved previously, create a new new one

    if (!self) {


        if (_idsByNameDict == nil) {
            _idsByNameDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        }

        if (_photosByNameDict == nil) {
            _photosByNameDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        }

        if (_installedByNameDict == nil) {
            _installedByNameDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        }

        if (_allFriendsArray == nil) {
            _allFriendsArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        }

        basicPermissions = NO;
        extendedPermissions = NO;

        // Create synchronous dispatch queue for all facebook activity
        if (_facebookUpdateQueue == nil) {
            _facebookUpdateQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.facebookUpdateQueue", NULL);
        }

    }
```

I think my general strategy is sound but I am tripping over how to actually grab the archived version of the manager during init!  Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Your class needs to implement `<NSCoding>` and both of its methods `encodeWithCoder:` to archive all of your property values and `initWithCoder:` to in archive them. Make sure to call super in the implementations. Generally, the class using the archived class would know about the archiving but you could hide that knowledge in `init` by using `initForReadingWithData:` to create your `NSKeyedUnarchiver` and then calling `[self initWithCoder:...];`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I think my problem is more to do with how I have written the top several lines of the init, and less to do with the implementation of NSCoding. I think this because I have already implemented NSCoding and both of those methods and I can see by examining the dir structure that I am successfully archiving to disc. The problem is limited to how to unarchive during init.  The good news is this: I have found another similar SO post, and that post contains a pretty good pattern which I will try using tonight when I get home:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981269/initwithcoder-works-but-init-seems-to-be-overwriting-my-objects-properties/2981453#2981453

Comment: Wow-wow-wow! Very dangerous suggestion! I read it and implement it as you describe. But in this case the child classes `initWithCoder` method not called! Spend all day to find what wrong! Use `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];`